# Factor $n$ in RSA if we know $φ(n)$

Tags: algorithms, cryptography

If we know that $n = 1363$ and $φ(n) = 1288$, how can we factor $n$?

Comment: For example by repeatedly trying all possible factors of $n$. $1363 =  29 \cdot 47$.

Comment: It was mentioned in the RSA paper, too; [Why is it important that phi(n) is kept a secret, in RSA?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/5791/18298)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n$ is the product of two distinct primes, say $n = pq$, then $\varphi(n) = (p-1)(q-1) = pq-(p+q)+1$. Therefore given $n$ and $\varphi(n)$ you can determine both $pq$ and $p+q$. By solving a quadratic equation, you can find both $p$ and $q$.